# Openlayers-3 forEachFeatureAtPixel slightly offset

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm currently using 3.6.0 and I'm finding that, as features are placed from left to right on the map that features further to the right seem to be offset from their icons - if I place my mouse directly over the graphic feature the mouse cursor (which is wired up to forEachFeatureAtPixel()) does not change until it is moved to the left of the feature icon.  On the left of the screen they line up, but it drifts going right until features on the right are completely out of sync.

Any ideas?  I thought it may be the library, but I've just rolled back to 3.4.0 and it was the same.

Could this be layout outside of the map canvas bumping items across the screen?

Comment: This was a stylesheet issue - literally a 10px padding added seemed to know the whole thing off.  Removing that padding fixed the issue - but I'm still not 100% sure why (CSS is like chewing gum in hair).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue for about a month but in my particular case the problem originated because I was rendering the map while showing a loading panel in front of it wich had a style that caused the web browser to display the scrollbars.

Upon load completion, hiding the loading panel also removed the scrollbar but somehow the map itself didn't refresh properly.

All I had to do was to force map to recalculate the viewport size using the `map.updateSize()`

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#updateSize